# Error 404 after inserting URL rewrite rule in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I want to redirect all url with uppercase to it lowercase version. For example:

https://www.droidafrica.net/Phone/Tecno-Spark-2-Go-Edition/ to
 https://www.droidafrica.net/phone/tecno-spark-2-go-edition/

I put the code below in web.config. It worked after applying changes, but most of the featured image thumbnails for devices specs gave error 404. Am I missing anything?

(I've temporarily removed the code though).

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="LowerCaseRule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Still wondering why I was getting error 404.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please do not make edits to the title just to bump the post. Consider where else you could get some support, and ask there, ensuring you add a link _from_ every duplicate _to_ every duplicate (and use cross-posting judiciously, since it has the capacity to waste other people's time and effort).

Comment: If your need is commercial, consider approaching a one-to-one paid assistance channel, like TopTal or AirPair. You may only need an hour of a person's time, and doing this will save you from being reliant on volunteers, who will (understandably) help only at their leisure.

Comment: Sir halfer, I actually made an amend to my post...not because I was trying to climb up the ladder again. By the way, found the answer already. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that work for me without adding further conditions; if you look closely, it a bit different from the first.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">  
        <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />  
        <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />  
        </rule>  
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

All thanks to [RuslanY Blog](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/#lower-case).